# Unity3D colliders act more like sponges than solid objects

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision, game-physics

I am making a platformer in Unity3D and I've noticed Unity3D's colliders are behaving weirdly in the simple sense that they don't seem to be solid.

To better demonstrate the problem I have used a simple sphere and cube and paused the game as the sphere "jumps"
Flipping through frames frame by frame you can clearly see the ball dip below the cube.

[image: Jump height]

[image: Just before hitting cube]

[image: Part of the sphere disappearing through the cube]

[image: How the ball lands]

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Are you using a Rigidbody? Try enabling CollisionDetection: Continuous on your rigidbody

Comment: Use a GIF instead of a series of image ._.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rigidbody has a set of option for collision detection. Different option provide different results but this is occuring because the detection is not checked frequently enough. You can switch to another option to improve this at a cost of performance. Here are a list of the options available and when they are best used.

```
1. Discrete - unless you experience problems you should use discrete. 
2. Continuous - for fast moving objects that are interacting with static geometry.
3. Continuous Dynamic -as above but are also interacting with other fast moving dynamic objects.
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I figured it would be something like this as it does look like it wasn't checking for a collision on every frame, thank you!

Comment: No problem, glad it helped :)